# Event Viewer errors GPO

Tags: windows-server-2003

there have been a few issues with the server i have been working on i check the event viewer and it is filled with the errors below i was not sure how to go about fixing this i looked in the path where the file is and it is there

Windows cannot access the file gpt.ini for GPO CN={31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9},CN=Policies,CN=System,DC=ISPHOME,DC=NET. The file must be present at the location <\isphome.net\sysvol\ISPHOME.NET\Policies{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}\gpt.ini>. (The network location cannot be reached. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help. ). Group Policy processing aborted.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Dimitri>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : ispserver
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : ISPHOME.NET
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : ISPHOME.NET

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/100 VE Network Connection #2

   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-07-E9-AA-3E-C3
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.50
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 127.0.0.1
*dcdiag /c /v is below*

         Summary of test results for DNS servers used by the above domain contro
llers:

            DNS server: 192.168.1.1 (<name unavailable>)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server

            DNS server: 192.168.1.50 (<name unavailable>)
               All tests passed on this DNS server
               This is a valid DNS server
               Name resolution is funtional. _ldap._tcp SRV record for the fores
t root domain is registered

         Summary of DNS test results:

                                            Auth Basc Forw Del  Dyn  RReg Ext
               ________________________________________________________________
            Domain: ISPHOME.NET
               ispserver                    PASS FAIL PASS PASS PASS PASS n/a

         ......................... ISPHOME.NET failed test DNS
```

Answer (score 1):

`{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}` is the GUID of a particular GPO on your Domain Controller(s). You need to find this GPO and temporarily disable it. This will help you narrow down whether you simply have an issue with that GPO or further issues.

You may be able to find out what GPO it represents using this Powershell command:

```
Get-GPO -GUID “{31B2F340-016D-11D2-945F-00C04FB984F9}”
```

If not, you'll have to manually go through each Policy and follow these steps:

> Using the "Active Directory Users and Computers" or "Active Directory
>   Sites and Services" administrative tool, click Properties on the
>   context menu of a domain, site, or organizational unit object in the
>   Active Directory. Click the Group Policy tab, click the GPO, and then
>   click Properties. The Unique Name field contains the GUID of the
>   selected GPO. Also note the Domain field. This is where the GPI is
>   stored, even though it may be used (linked to) by other domains.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216359